# Editar variables de entorno

Tags: windows, variables, windows10

Instale el JDK de Java y necesito agregar el bin a la variable de entorno del sistema PATH. El problema es que en las opciones no puedo editar. Antes en otro computador me habilitaba las 3 opciones disponibles pero en mi actual Windows no me deja.

[image: Como se puede observar en la imagen que tengo las opciones deshabilitadas]

Como puedo tener disponibles esas opciones. Cabe destacar que mi usuario es un Administrador.

Answer (score 0):

Si a veces eso suele pasar cuando accedes directamente, no te sé decir el porqué, pero la solución es entrar a través de las propiedades del sistema es decir, sigue estos pasos:

`Inicio --> Editar Variables de Entorno del sistema -->  Variables de entorno.`

Espero que te ayude de esta manera.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sé que ha sido pero ahora tengo todas las opciones habilitadas.